# How can I launch a new navigation graph, on FAB clicked?

Tags: android, navigation, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

### Problem:

I am new in Android and I think I am just getting something very wrong conceptually. 
I can't have two navHostFragments in the same activity. I get this error.

> Error inflating class fragment

The bottomNavigationView graph works very good by itself, and I can switch tabs without problems, the trouble comes when trying to add a new navigation on FAB click.  **I don't want to replace the fragment container with the new one, I want to launch a new fragment that will be full screen**

### Context:

- In the Main Activity I have a **collapsible toolbar, bottomNavigationView and FAB button**. I also want to have two NavHostFragment, one for each navigation graph.
- **First navigation graph** handles the switching between the bottomNavigationView tabs (the content of the fragments appears below the collapsible toolbar and on top of the bottomNavigationView)
- **Second navigation graph** will appear on FAB clicked, and will be full screen

### What I have:

This is how activity_main.xml looks like

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            .....
        />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/waiterNavigationHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="false"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/waiter_navigation" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">  

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_navigation" />

        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                .........
            />
            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                ........
            />
        </FrameLayout>
```

This is waiter_navigation.xml that should appear full screen on FAB click:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/waiter_screen">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/waiter_screen"
        android:name=".app.ui.waiter.WaiterScreenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_waiter"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_waiter" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_menu_screen"
            app:destination="@id/menuScreenFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_screen"
        android:name=".app.ui.menu.MenuScreenFragment"
        android:label="MenuScreenFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" />
</navigation>
```

This is bottom_navigation.xml that goes between the collapsible app bar and the bottomNavigationView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_screen">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_screen"
        android:name=".app.ui.home.HomeScreenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_receipt_screen"
            app:destination="@id/receipt_screen"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/receipt_screen"
        android:name=".app.ui.receipt.ReceiptScreenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_explore"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_receipt" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_profile_screen"
            app:destination="@id/profile_screen"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_screen"
        android:name=".app.ui.profile.ProfileScreenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_more"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />

</navigation>
```

### Full Error details

> 2020-02-24 11:54:30.401 16857-16857/com.restaurant.app
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.restaurant.app, PID: 16857
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.restaurant.app/com.restaurant.app.ui.main.MainScreenActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML
>   file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no start destination defined via app:startDestination for
>   com.flypay.restaurant.app:id/waiter_screen
>           at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:61)
>           at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
>           at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:933)
>           at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:577)
>           at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:534)
>           at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:499)
>           at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:481)
>           at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:237)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:109)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:784)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.flypay.restaurant.app.ui.main.MainScreenActivity.onCreate(MainScreenActivity.kt:17)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
>   2020-02-24 11:54:30.402 16857-16857/com.restaurant.app
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Comment: please post the error

Comment: this is the issue => "no start destination defined via app:startDestination for com.flypay.restaurant.app:id/waiter_screen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@id/ADD_SCREEN_NAME"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/waiter_screen">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/waiter_screen"
        android:name=".app.ui.waiter.WaiterScreenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_waiter"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_waiter" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_menu_screen"
            app:destination="@id/menuScreenFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_screen"
        android:name=".app.ui.menu.MenuScreenFragment"
        android:label="MenuScreenFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! this actually solves the error! 
Do you know however how to launch a new navigation graph on button clicked? Right now the view is there already because putting the start Destination already fills the fragment. Or should I just hide it somehow?